# How to show an alert in Swift UIAlertView not working

Tags: swift, alert

I want to show an alert, but UIAlertView isn't working in swift.
How can I do this?
This is how I do it in objective-c but when I try to convert it to swift code it doesn't work.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" 
                                              message:@"Message"
                                             delegate:nil
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];


[alert show];
```

Comment: you should know that : the UIAlertView is deprecated now you should use UIAlertController

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `UIAlertController`

`UIAlertView` is deprecated.

You can show an alert with this code:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "test", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: UIAlertView deprecated? I can't find that anywhere.

Comment: On UIAlertView click Jump to definition, then you will see a comment // UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController

Answer (score 2):

```
let myAlert = UIAlertView()    
myAlert.title = "Title"   
myAlert.message = "My message"   
myAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")   
myAlert.delegate = self   
myAlert.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIAlertController, use the following code.

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello  Coders", message: "Visit www.simplifiedios.net to learn xcode", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close Alert", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Reference: [Show Alert in iOS](https://www.simplifiedios.net/ios-show-alert-using-uialertcontroller/)